# Any reference doc /model/ implementation of enforcing events dependency/ordering in distributed computing?

Tags: distributed-computing

For example, Process P is listening to events E(A) and E(B), but to process either of the events, P needs the other event available too. Naively, when P receives either of the events, it will check if the other event is already received. If not, it can wait. But

1) this does not sound very efficient, especially when each process has many different types of events to process.

2) Also as the number of distributed processes increases to a large number, events are more tangled between processes, processes dies/restarts, etc. all these make the events handling more complicated.

So I would like to know if there are any reference doc / model/ implementations for events handling under such a distributed computing environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this coordination using workflow/saga techniques.

Your process defines a workflow (state machine) that can be initiated on receipt of either E(A) or E(B).

For example: on receipt of E(A) your Process service initiates a workflow that begins waiting for a matching E(B) message. Subsequent receipt of E(B) message will resume the workflow originally started by E(A).

In between workflow initiation and resumption, you might consider storing workflow in persistent storage to survive termination of your Process service.

The [documentation on Sagas (workflow)](http://www.nservicebus.com/Sagas.aspx) from NServiceBus explains this concept well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this pattern to me. just curious how this pattern would perform in a very performance demanding embeded environment.